# How to transform Capsule Component in UE4?

Tags: fbx, collider

The collision of the character with the environment only works correctly (in the eyes) when I use the original skeletal mesh.

I tested it in the most varied sizes and it worked perfectly.

[image]

It turns out that when I import any 3D object (FBX of Blender), it does not work properly (though the UE4 says that in the import it makes several adjustments).

[image]

I realized that the problem is because of the **capsule component**, which is responsible for detecting the character's collision with the environment. So at first I would like to know how to **increase its size and make modifications**.

[image]

Links that I researched and that helped me in some way:

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/853084/is-it-possible-to-transform-the-capsule-component.html

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/200546/change-the-capsule-component.html

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/465122/how-to-change-character-capsule-component-location.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can not click on the capsule component only.

To change the dimensions of the capsule component, simply type 'capsule' in the search box that will appear two edit boxes: lighting and shape.

[image]

It is not possible to change the position of the capsule component, but it is possible to change the position of the character mesh. Just double click on the character that it becomes possible to change the position of the mesh.

[image]

References:

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/200546/change-the-capsule-component.html

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/465122/how-to-change-character-capsule-component-location.html